# Can addEventListener fire event for mobile display?

Tags: responsive-design, addeventlistener

Not good with js at all. I am using jquery TimeCircles (http://plugins.jquery.com/timecircles/). And I am trying to 'rebuild' (http://git.wimbarelds.nl/TimeCircles/readme.php) the circles when the view / window goes from portrait to landscape.

The div that has the circles is:

```
<div id="DateCountdown" data-date="2015-10-08 00:00:00" ></div>
```

My goal is like i mentioned above, would like to have the circles rebuild themselves when view changes from landscape to portrait or vice versa.

I have this right before the closing body tag:

```
<script>
// Find matches
var mql = window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)");

// If there are matches, we're in portrait
if(mql.matches) {  
    // Portrait orientation
} else {  
    // Landscape orientation
}

// Add a media query change listener
mql.addListener(function(m) {
    if(m.matches) {
        $(".datecountdown").TimeCircles().rebuild(); 
    }
    else {


    }
});

</script>
```